# Python TKinter: can you remove/forget multiple widgets from a window with a single command/ line of code

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a program with TKinter and am wondering if there is a more efficient way to delete widgets from the window.

I am aware you can delete them 1 by one with:

```
widget_name.forget()
```

is there a more efficient and less tedious way to delete them? Like a delete all command?

Comment: delete/forget their parent

Answer (score 3):

As has been suggested, if the widgets in question are contained in a parent element like a `Frame`, "forgetting" the parent will also forget its children.

Another option: if the widgets in question share a parent, you can try the following

```
# this is useful when you want to keep 'parent' but not its children
# just replace 'parent' with whatever widget's children you want to remove
for widget in parent.winfo_children()
    widget.forget()
```

Comment: Yes i have tried it and it works thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help! If this worked for you, please accept the answer so others know this question has been answered.